# Double to String - Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

How can I format double to string keeping the value of the decimal point, but without showing decimal point.

Example:

```
Double: 21.75
```

Format for

```
String: 0002175
```

Comment: Did you try calling `FormatFloat()` with `(T)FormatSettings.DecimalSeparator` set to #0?

Comment: This way does not works, result in the following format 000021. I would like to leave only numbers without calling another function. Calling another function already works. But I believe it would be more elegant by formatting.

Comment: I double-checked, and *most* uses of `DecimalSeparator` do not allow it to be #0 (one case does, but it does not apply here). You could, however, format the Double normally, then strip out the `DecimalSeparator` afterwards. Not ideal, but I don't see any other option: `StringReplace(FormatFloat(...), DecimalSeparator, '', [])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that manually in a single line like Remy suggests:

```
text := StringReplace(FormatFloat('0.00', yourNumber), DecimalSeparator, '', []);
```

That will format the float as you need and replace decimal separator symbol with nothing - effectively omitting it.

Take note to force trailing zeroes, so that your resulting numbers are in the same order of magnitude.